# How to parse string to JSON in Ember Handlebar

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using Ember 2.16.0 and I can import string into Handlebar but when I try to access JSON property I am not getting expected result. Is there a helper that will convert a string into JSON inside Handlebar template?

Comment: Hi ziveo! Can you share some code? I think I need more context to understand what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the answer the OP posted, except I'd make the `schemaJson` property a computed property so that if `schemasString` changed, it would automatically update:

```
export default Component.extend({
  schemasJson: computed('schemasString', function() {
    return JSON.parse(this.schemasString);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the intent of Handlebars is to keep as much logic out of the template as possible, so more typically in Ember you might perform the JSON parsing in a class, like a controller or component. That way by the time the data is sent to the template it’s already in the final data format you need. Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like this to make data available to the component template. Not 100% sure if this is the best approach.

```
export default Component.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('schemasJson', Ember.$.parseJSON(this.schemasString));
  }
});
```

Comment: I'd consider using JSON.parse instead of the jQuery $.parseJSON method to lessen your dependency on jQuery